# xpath expression to access tags after script

Tags: xpath

I have some problem getting all the html tags after script using Xpath

```
my html :
<table dir = "rtl .......">
<tbody>
<script src = "get.aspx?type=js&file=ajax&rev=3"......>
<script language = "JavaScript"......>
<script>..</script>
<tr>
<td id = "jm0x1"some code here...>
<td id = "jm0x2"some code here...>
also a lot of <tr> here....
</tbody>
```

how i can access all (td id = "jm0x..)

this is the page i want to parse: http://kooora.com/?c=6423

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
//td[contains(@id, "jm0x")]
```

Then you can affine the contains string to the pattern you want.

Comment: If something doesn't work, please say exactly what you did and exactly how it failed.

Comment: It's weird. It's the second time that I test my XPath expression with xmllint based on libxml2 and they do work, but apparently when one tries them using HPPLE it does not.

Comment: thats true Spredzy with HPPLE does not work.is there other solution?

Comment: HI Michael Kay,i am making an iphone app that get data from web server so i parse the content of html using HPPLE (kind of library). so when i use an expression like this //script[@language='JavaScript']/following::tr/td[contains(@id, "jm0x1")] this return 0.i can't access the inner html of <tr> tag

Comment: i think that those tags are not in the html source code  they are being added after the fact via javascript but the question:how to get theme?